# Pyinstaller failing to find scipy modules

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When packaging a python app with pyinstaller, I keep getting recurring ImportError relating to scipy modules. How can I fix this one time, without having to restart the  build everytime?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by manually adding the --hidden-import flag to specify all the missing modules. It was painful because I had to build, wait for it to fail because of a missing module, note the module down, and repeat the process. In the end, I manually specified 17 modules to be imported. Works great now